# foreign key constraint fails although inserted right

Tags: mysql

I'm just starting with SQL and this problem occurred while running my file. 
The primary key in table Artikel is artikelNr and table Assortiment has a multiple key, namely artikelNr and winkelNaam. We have already searched on the internet but didn't find any useful information. thanks in advance!

This is our SQL code in Java:

```
public void addArtikel(String artikelNr, String artikelNaam, double prijs, double aantalBonuspunten, double aantalBonuspuntenNodig,int  minAantalStuks, double minBedrag)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Connection con = null;
    try
     {  
         con = db.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO  Artikel\n" +"VALUES(‘" + artikelNr + "’, ‘" + artikelNaam + "’, " + prijs + ", " + aantalBonuspunten + ", " + aantalBonuspuntenNodig + ", " + minAantalStuks + "," + minBedrag + ");";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        con.close();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         try { con.close(); } catch(Exception ex2){};
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
}

public void addAssortiment(String artikelNr, String winkelNaam)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Connection con = null;
    try
     {   
         con = db.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Assortiment\n" +"VALUES('" + artikelNr+ "', '" + winkelNaam + "');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        con.close();
     }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         try { con.close(); } catch(Exception ex2){};
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
}
```

This is our Java code:

```
    public void artikelToevoegen(String winkelnaam)
    {
         String artikelNr = io.readString("Geef de barcode van het artikel dat u wilt toevoegen: ");
        while(artikelNr.length() != 13)
        {
            artikelNr = io.readString("Ongeldige barcode. Een barcode bestaat uit 13 karakters. Probeer opnieuw: ");
        }
        String naam = io.readString("Geef naam artikel");
        double prijs = io.readDouble("Geef prijs artikel");
        double aantalBonuspunten = io.readDouble("Geef het aantal punten per artikel (niet per euro van de prijs!)" + "\ndie men krijgt bij aankoop van het artikel (als de vereisten voldaan zijn)."
                + "\nDe punten moeten tussen 0,25 en 2 per euro van de prijs liggen." 
                +"\nIndien dit aantal 0 is typ null." 
                + "\nIndien het artikel niet aan deze vereisten voldoet, wordt het automatisch verwijderd.");
        int minAantalStuks = io.readInt("Geef het minimum aantal stuks dat gekocht moet worden van het artikel" +"\n eer men de bijhorende punten verkrijgt, indien er geen vereist aantal is typ 1");
        double aantalBonuspuntenNodig = io.readDouble("Geef het aantal punten per artikel (niet per euro van de prijs!) die nodig zijn om het artikel gratis te verkrijgen (indien aan de voorwaarden voldaan is)."
                + "\n De punten moeten tussen 0,25 en 2 per euro van de prijs liggen." + "\n Indien dit aantal 0 is typ null." + 
                "\n Indien het artikel niet aan deze vereisten voldoet, wordt het automatisch verwijderd.");
        double minBedrag = io.readDouble("Geef het minimum bedrag dat van het artikel aangekocht moet worden eer men het artikel met punten kan verkrijgen," + "\n indien er geen minimumbedrag is geef de eenheidsprijs."); 
        db.addArtikel(artikelNr, naam, prijs, aantalBonuspunten, aantalBonuspuntenNodig, minAantalStuks, minBedrag);
        db.addAssortiment(artikelNr, winkelnaam);
        int keuze = io.readInt("Wilt u nog een artikel toevoegen?" + 
                          "\n1)Ja" + "\n2)nee");
        while(keuze<1||keuze>2)
        {
            keuze = io.readInt("Ongeldige keuze, probeer opnieuw" + "\nWilt u nog een artikel toevoegen?" + 
                          "\n1)Ja" + "\n2)nee");
        }
        while(keuze != 2)
        {
            switch(keuze)
         {
            case 1: artikelToevoegen(winkelnaam);
                    break;

          }
        }

    }
```

This is our error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘1231231231231’, ‘cola can’, 1.2, 1.2, 1.25, 1,5.0)' at line 2
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`BINFG21`.`Assortiment`, CONSTRAINT `Assortiment_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`artikelNr`) REFERENCES `Artikel` (`artikelNr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘Delhaize’)' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the error yet, but please have a look at SQL Injection ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection ) and PreparedStatements. Your application begs for being attacked and it will crash at the slightest invalid input.

Prepared Statement also help to avoid these ugly syntax errors because of their better readability.

Back to your error: Looks like the first statement fails and the second one does belong to the record which wasn't inserted because of the first error.
Have a look at the content of the String variables used for SQL and insert them into a SQL-Tool like phpmyadmin to check wether it can be executed.

Comment: Can you please post the way you solved it? This would help others to understand.

Comment: The main thing that went wrong was the difference in apotrophe. we used a mack to implement, but our program does not recognize these kind of apostrophe. But there were a lot of other errors to.